# Managed Metadata Service is disabled, but term store is working

Tags: managed-metadata, mms

Basically everything is in the title. 
The Managed Metadata Service in the CA is currently disabled, but the Managed Metadata service application is working as expected.

Is that normal ? Shouldn't the service still be enabled ?

Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: can you add some screen shot, where you saw it is disable? how many server in the farm, may be you are looking on a server it is disable but on other server it is running?

Comment: any update on the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can double check:
First, go to the Central admin -> Application Management -> Manage Services on server -> make sure that Manage Metadata Web Service is started
[image]
Second, in application management -> select Service Application -> and make sure that you have already had the Managed Metadata service
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may have the service deployed and running on more than 1 SharePoint Server.

Check "Services on Server" for each of the SharePoint machines in the farm.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just realised this is an OLLLLD question! Not sure why it was at the top of the front page!

Comment: The question is "bumped to the homepage" by system